# Print pyObjC version installed?

Tags: python, terminal, version, pyobjc, interactive-shell

I've recently started programming "Objective C" in python using the excellent pyObjC extension. I'm using macOS High Sierra (10.13.4) with apple's stock python 2.7.10 installation. That part was easy to find out using an interactive python shell:

```
>>> import platform
>>> platform.python_version()
```

How can I do the same for the installed pyObjC extension?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Using an interactive shell:**

```
>>> import objc
>>> objc.__version__
```

**Using pip in terminal:**

```
pip list | grep pyobjc-core
```